# LINQ to Entities: DB connection failed

Tags: linq, entity-framework, database-connection

I've just converted my data access from Linq to SQL to Linq to Entities.  I've created my edms and a have updated my class as follows but I'm getting any error that the connection is not found.  **The error is in the ModelDesigner.cs file**.  Any help on this?  Thanks ~susan~

**Error report:**

> The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid.

```
Line 48:         /// Initializes a new FVTCEntities object using the connection string found in the 'FVTCEntities' section of the application configuration file.
Line 49:         /// </summary>
Line 50:         public FVTCEntities() : base("name=FVTCEntities", "FVTCEntities")
Line 51:         {
Line 52:             this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

**Here is my code for my Data Access Layer:**

```
namespace DL
{
    public class DLgetRestaurants
    {
        FVTCEntities db = new FVTCEntities();

        public List<RESTAURANT> getRestaurants(string cuisineName)
        {
            var cuisineID = db.CUISINEs.First(s => s.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName).CUISINE_ID;

            List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITY").Include("CUISINE") 
                                       where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID 
                                       select RESTAURANT).ToList();


             return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are your connection string doesn't have the metadata resources specified. Can you post your connection string?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx

Comment: here is the connection from the App_Code file:<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FVTCEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SFP;attachdbfilename=H:\ASP.Net\FVRG\FVRG\App_Data\FVTC.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: If you put a breakpoint and using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings do you definitely see your connection string in there?

Comment: Sorry, I've not used Confg Mgr before.  I've opened BUILD . CONFIGURATION MANAGER.  How do I select ConnectionStrings???  Aslo, should the breakpoint be set in my Designer file where it errors?

Comment: Yes, set your breakpoint there. Then in the watch window, add a watch for System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings and make sure you can see your connection string in there at runtime.

Comment: I've resolved the problem!!!  I've copied the <ConnectionString> from the app.config file (where the wizard put it) and put in in the Web.config file.  Whoopee!!  Thanks for your help!!!